# Mapping on Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mapping

I'm working a mapping solution for my community college.

I know, there's Dreamweaver plotting tools, but I searching for the best practices. More CSS3/HMTL/JS.

Something similar to http://www.thewarzcartographer.com/

Can anyone give advice or tips where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Maps API with custom tiles. Your tiles need to be 256 x 256 pixels.

See this link for more details:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/custommap.htm

And here for an example:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_custommap1.htm